# Storing/loading PNGs from In App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm developing IAPs for my app. I'm able to create the IAP package, upload to iTunes Connect and download to my to app from the App Store sandbox, and read the contents. What I'm still unclear on though is where to copy the contents of the IAP to store/load them most efficiently.

The contents of the IAP package is a set of PNGs that the user can use to customize their appearance with while using the app. The user gets a default set of PNGs with the app itself.

A few couple questions this has led to:

1. Where is the preferred location for storing the PNGs from the IAP? Some tutorials recommend **NSDocumentDirectory** while others recommend **NSApplicationSupportDirectory**. What are the advantages of one over the other?
2. How can I load the PNGs without having to track which ones are in the main bundle and which are in the IAP directory? For example, the default PNGs in the main app bundle can be loaded with:

   ```
   UIImage *newHat = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fancyHat.png"];
   ```

   While the PNGs from the IAPs have to be loaded like this (assuming I've copied them to the Document directory):

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *inAppImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iapTopHat.png"];
   UIImage *newHat = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:inAppImagePath];
   ```

   Is it possible to reconcile these, so I don't have to track which PNGs are IAPs and which are in the main bundle and then use two separate methods to load them?

It seems like ideally I could copy the PNGs to the main app bundle so I could use `UIImage imageNamed:`. But that seems to not be allowed and not preferred anyway.

Any assistance or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here is a good start for what Apple suggests for data storage locations: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html
2. You have multiple options for digging into the bundled vs purchased content. In your example, your image name is prefixed by something that could be used to differentiate categories of content, so you can use that to determine which loading mechanism to use. You could reverse the method you ponder in the post, that is to check for the existence of the asset (whatever the name) in the bundle first, and load from there or the purchased location if not found. You could also create symlinks into the bundle if you wanted to unify the sets "on disk", but this one is trickier as you'll need to make sure your symlinks get updated if the base App UUID changes (which it will and often) during development.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You answer on the second point is similar to my current approach. Right now when I download the IAPs I add a prefix to the filename and then store that file name in the local database. Then I created a subclass of UIImage that checks the filename for that prefix and loads from the appropriate location. I've had to update some calls to UIImage, but less painful than I originally anticipated.

Comment: Glad it was useful. There is no one "right" answer, but it seems you found one that is right for you.